# MySql Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE)

Tags: mysql

When I ran this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM text_trainer    
WHERE text LIKE '%@CommonBlackGirI: Tyree from Straight Outta Compton %'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I faced this error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

I tried some solution .BUT not working. I want search this  line :

"@CommonBlackGirI: Tyree from Straight Outta Compton "

in text column .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two strings with different charsets/collations, latin1 in column text vs utf8 in LIKE operator. MySQL do not know how to do it correctly. You should convert column values to utf8 firstly -

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  text_trainer
WHERE
  CONVERT(text USING utf8) LIKE '%@CommonBlackGirI: Tyree from Straight Outta Compton %'
```

Comment: still facing this error :

_#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like_

Comment: You can use CAST/CONVERT function for the LIKE value, also try to add SET NAMES utf8; SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'; statements to setup mysql session.